# Assigning values to all rows within a specific hour range using monthly data

Tags: r, date, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
temp:
    id time       date
    1  06:22:30   2018-01-01
    2  08:58:00   2018-01-15
    3  09:30:21   2018-01-30
```

The actual data set continues on for 9000 rows with obs for times throughout the month of January. I want to write a code that will assign each row a new value depending on which hour range the time variable belongs to.

A couple of example hour ranges would be:

```
Morning peak: 06:00:00 - 08:59:00 
Morning: 09:00:00 - 11:59:00
```

The desired output would look like this:

```
id time       date        time_of_day
1  06:22:30   2018-01-01  MorningPeak
2  08:58:00   2018-01-15  MorningPeak
3  09:30:21   2018-01-30  Morning
```

I have tried playing around with time objects using the chron package using the following code to specify different time ranges:

```
MorningPeak <- temp[temp$Time >= "06:00:00" & temp$Time <= "08:59:59",]
MorningPeak$time_of_day <- "MorningPeak"
Morning <- temp[temp$Time >= "09:00:00" & temp$Time <= "11:59:59",]
Midday$time_of_day <- "Morning"
```

The results could then be merged and then manipulated to get everything in the same column. Is there a way to do this such that the desired result is generated and no extra data manipulation is required? I am interested in learning how to make my code more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing characters and not time/datetime objects, you need to convert it to date-time before comparison. It seems you can compare the hour of the day to get appropriate labels.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(hour  = as.integer(format(as.POSIXct(time, format = "%T"), "%H")), 
         time_of_day = case_when(hour >= 6 & hour < 9 ~ "MorningPeak", 
                                 hour >= 9 & hour < 12 ~ "Morning", 
                                 TRUE ~ "Rest of the day"))

#  id     time       date hour time_of_day
#1  1 06:22:30 2018-01-01    6 MorningPeak
#2  2 08:58:00 2018-01-15    8 MorningPeak
#3  3 09:30:21 2018-01-30    9     Morning
```

You can add more hourly criteria if needed.

---

We can also use `cut`

```
cut(as.integer(format(as.POSIXct(df$time, format = "%T"), "%H")), 
    breaks = c(-Inf, 6, 9, 12, Inf), right = FALSE,
   labels = c("Rest of the day", "MorningPeak", "Morning", "Rest of the day"))
```